# Yii framework (require and redirect)

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
    $filename ='here is the name of the file ,the name is correct and i can print it';
    require($filename); //this sentenct give me the problem

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $text[$key] = array_merge($text[$key],$value);
    }

    //protection ????
    $tout = "<?php \n";
    $tout .= '$text = array ( ' . "\n";
    foreach($text as $key => $value)
    {
        $tout .= '    "' . $key . '" => array( ' . "\n";
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
        {
            $tout .= '        "' . $key2 . '" => "' . $value2 . '",'. "\n";
        }
        $tout .= "    ), \n";
    }
    $tout .= "); \n";
    $tout .= "?> \n";

    $fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Could not open log file.");
    fwrite($fh, $tout) or die("Could not write file!");
    fclose($fh);
    return true;
}
```

I have a problem whereby I am sending a request to save data and if it works I want it to redirect, but when i do that I get blank page.

```
 return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('./index.php?r=' . $pages_link[$index + 1])
```

If I remove `require($filename);` the redirect will work perfectly but the data doesn't get saved (because I  don't get the data from the file)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try checking to see if the file exists first, just to be sure. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: with least understanding of what you are trying to do, i suggest check if path is proper, since require need complete path to the file..

Comment: Possible problems: `exit` in included file, syntax error in included file, output buffering activated in included file, infinite redirections/inclusions, ... First make sure that all errors are being reported, otherwise you're gonna be hunting ghosts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Solution was found thanks to the suggestions of a member of yiiframework forum.
For details. see
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69109-yii-redirect-after-require/